# get id inside circle with python and mysql

Tags: python, mysql, geometry

I have two points A(lat1,lng1) and B(lat2,lng2) and I want to get all the ids of a MySQL table inside those two points (A and B as a diameter of a circle ).
How can I do that? I am a little bit stuck
thank you very much
[see this image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/flr3z.png)

Comment: Do you mean that you have a table with coordinates and given two points, calculate a circle with these two as edges and figure out what other rows in this table would be inside this circle? Are you limited to MySQL only or can you do the circle calculation outside of MySQL? Also, what have you tried so far?

Comment: For inner points `|AC|^2 + |CB|^2 < |AB|^2`.

Comment: @SimonS. yes. I have a table of restaurants with their coordinates (lat, lng) and I need to know how many other restaurants are located inside within the circle where restaurant A and restaurant B are the diameter of the circle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example I have two points that I want to search points within those two defined points. I calculate the distance between those two points and divided by two to get the radius. Latitude of center = (lat_point1 + lat_point2)/2 and same for longitude. Then I search from this center all the points within the radius.

```
SET center = ST_GeomFromText( 'POINT(35.322825 139.52769)', 4326 ); #center  between spot_1 and 2
SET spot_1 = ST_GeomFromText( 'POINT(35.30633 139.50644 )', 4326 );
SET spot_2 = ST_GeomFromText( 'POINT(35.33932 139.54894 )', 4326 );

SELECT id, lat, lng, ROUND(ST_Distance(geometry, center, 'kilometre'), 2) FROM points where ST_Distance(spot_2 ,geometry, 'kilometre') <=radius
```